# Can I get RSpec `expect().to(raise_error))` to print the return value it shouldn't have received?

Tags: exception, rspec

I'm writing some Rspec tests for exceptional conditions. I'm accustomed to writing the equivalent of this in other languages:

```
it 'explodes on something bad' do
  actual = funny_function()
  raise "This should have thrown, but received #{actual}"
rescue StandardError => e
  expect(e).to(be_instance_of(MyLovelyError))
  expect(e.message).to(eq('You are delightfully whimsical'))
end
```

because I find it useful, when tests fail, for the report to be immediately informative, rather than being forced to re-run the test in the debugger.

Rspec's special exception syntax swallows the actual value, and merely says '... but nothing was raised' which is a bit weak. I can do this...

```
def expect_raise
  expect { raise("Expected failure, but actual=#{yield}") }
end

expect_raise { funny_function() }.to(raise_error(MyLovelyError, 'You are delightfully whimsical'))
```

but that feels clunky: it seems Rspec should have a decorator of some kind to display 'actual' already in this case. I sniffed through the documentation, but didn't spot anything.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the stock rspec matchers.

But `raise_error` is just that, a matcher, and your best chance would be to write your own, which is surprisingly easy to do.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/custom-matchers

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher

You can also check the implementation of the `raise_error` for inspiration:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/raise_error.rb#L51:L58

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that there's no provision for this. I'm writing in Ruby through gritted teeth, so I'm going to stick with my implementation above: I don't mind using existing stuff if it's there, but my energies are going towards migrating the codebase to Kotln, not digging deeper into Ruby.